# PHP method can't return two dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I stuck on really strange thing.

I'm writing simple PHP MVC WebApp for school project and I can't return two dimensional array.

I solve this problem this way:

```
class Post{
    public $author;
    public $cat;
    public $table;
    function getPosts($cat = ""){
        dbstart();
        global $dbconn;
        empty($cat) ? $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM pytania") : $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE cat = $cat");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $output[] = $row;
        $this -> table = $output;   
        dbstop();
        }
    }       

}
```

It works perfectly when I'm calling property in controller

```
"poststable" => $post -> table
```

Gives me all four posts (two dimensional array with 4 rows) but I want to remove public $table property so I can directly call method like this way:

```
 "poststable" => $post -> getPosts($cat)
```

Unfortunately, when I change my method code with this:

```
return $output;
```

$data "poststable" Gives me only first post (array stores only one post)

Anyone has idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Where you put `return $output;` in your code?

Comment: Of course I want to put: return $output; instead of $this -> table = $output;

Comment: Given that you're setting `$this -> table = $output;` inside your loop; were you simply trying to change that to a `return $output;`, or were you returning after the loop when `$output` has been completely built?

Comment: So that's because you get only one post. After first loop of `while` you return value and loop stops processing here. Return `$output` after while loop.

Comment: I'm idiot :) Thank you, that's it!

Comment: i'm not sure but `dbstop();` if this method close the connection ... it will return only one record.

Comment: Yes, I moved that too.

Comment: I made simple MVC from scratch that's main objective in my school project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build up the entire output in the *while loop*, after which you can return it. In addition, you should do your DB clean up outside the loop.

```
<?php
class Post{
    public $author;
    public $cat;
    function getPosts($cat = ""){
        dbstart();
        global $dbconn;

        empty($cat) 
            ? $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM pytania") 
            : $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE cat = $cat");

        // Use an array as your return value
        $output = [];
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            // Build up the array
            $output[] = $row;
        }

        // Do your clean up out here
        dbstop();

        // Now return the result
        return $output;
    }       

}
```